# Swing Graphics Not Working In My Line Algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, swing, line, draw

I'm trying to utilize swing graphics in order to gauge Bresenham's algorithm against a less polished solution (I haven't implemented the timers yet). As things stand, there are no errors when compiling, and it throws a NullPointer exception at basic, drawthoselines, and main. The idea is that the lines will appear in the JFrame, but they don't. It's just a blank frame. I know I have everything set to static, but I get a lot of errors otherwise.

I'm a novice and I would be grateful to anyone who could provide a solution and an explanation.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class lines extends JPanel {

static int deltaX;
static int deltaY;
static int DY2;
static int DX2;
static int Di;

public static void main (String[] args) {
JFrame f = new JFrame("Line vs Line");
f.pack();
f.setVisible(true);
f.setSize(300,300);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
JPanel p = new JPanel();
f.getContentPane().add(p);
Graphics g = null;
drawthoselines(g);
}

public static void basic(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Graphics g){
int deltaX = x2-x1;
int deltaY = y2-y1;
float m = (float)deltaY/(float)deltaX;
float c = y1 - (m*x1);
for (int x=x1; x<x2; x++){
float floatY = (m*x) + c;
int y = Math.round(floatY);
g.drawLine(x,y,x,y);
}
}

public static void brz(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Graphics g){
deltaX = x2-x1;
deltaY = y2-y1;
DY2 = 2* deltaY;
DX2 = 2* deltaX;
Di = DY2 - deltaX;
int x = x1;
int y = y1;
int prevy;
while (x<x2) {
x++;
prevy = y;
if (Di > 0){
y++;
}
g.drawLine(x,y,x,y);
Di = Di + DY2 - (DX2 * (y - prevy));
}
}

public static void drawthoselines(Graphics g){
basic(10,10,40,30,g);
basic(10,10,40,90,g);
brz(50,50,150,60,g);
brz(50,50,150,120,g);
brz(50,50,150,140,g);
}

}
```

Comment: Well `Graphics g = null; drawthoselines(g);` looks like to *could* be problematic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't instantiate Graphics because it is passed down from the java.awt.event
Also you have a class that extends JPanel, which means you want to add the class to the JFrame by instantiating the class. Also, the class will implicitly call paintComponent method which you will override to make use of the Graphics g. It's a lot of stuff to take in so go slowly (start from rudimentary examples).

Let me also inform you a bit on static modifier.
Static modifier runs when you load the class. Thus if a method that is not a static is in a static method, the method will need to be called by instantiating the object that holds the method. Because you need the object (class) loaded to be able to use the method.

Below should work:
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

```
public class lines extends JPanel {

static int deltaX;
static int deltaY;
static int DY2;
static int DX2;
static int Di;

public static void main (String[] args) {
JFrame f = new JFrame("Line vs Line");
f.pack();
f.setVisible(true);
f.setSize(300,300);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
lines h = new lines();
f.getContentPane().add(h);

}

public static void basic(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Graphics g){
int deltaX = x2-x1;
int deltaY = y2-y1;
float m = (float)deltaY/(float)deltaX;
float c = y1 - (m*x1);
for (int x=x1; x<x2; x++){
float floatY = (m*x) + c;
int y = Math.round(floatY);
g.drawLine(x,y,x,y);
}
}

public static void brz(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Graphics g){
deltaX = x2-x1;
deltaY = y2-y1;
DY2 = 2* deltaY;
DX2 = 2* deltaX;
Di = DY2 - deltaX;
int x = x1;
int y = y1;  
int prevy;
while (x<x2) {
x++;
prevy = y;
if (Di > 0){
y++;
}
g.drawLine(x,y,x,y);
Di = Di + DY2 - (DX2 * (y - prevy));
}
}

public static void drawthoselines(Graphics g){

}
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
basic(10,10,40,30,g);
basic(10,10,40,90,g);
brz(50,50,150,60,g);
brz(50,50,150,120,g);
brz(50,50,150,140,g);
}

}
```

Comment: `start from rudimentary examples).` - this is not a good example to start with. As already mentioned, the tutorial will explain the basics with properly structured classes the don't use static variables and methods among other things.

Answer (score 2):

That is not the way you do custom painting. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for explanations on how painting works and for working examples.

Also, whenever you see all static variables and method you know you are doing something else wrong. I suggest you take time to read other section of the tutorial as well since they all contain examples on a better way to structure your code.